# Android SpeechRecognizer distance to microphone feedback using speech sound level

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, distance, microphone

I am software engineer and newbie in Android "Speech To Text" field.
Currently I am trying to build an Android app that uses “Speech To Text” using Google SpeechRecognizer and I want to add a feature that gives users a feedback while speaking about how close they speak to microphone.
e.g. if they speak close enough to microphone it should display a green color on the screen, it means OK.
if they speak to far from microphone it should display a red color on the screen meaning not OK.

I’ve been trying to do this using onRmsChanged method in Google SpeechRecognizer and based on rmsdB values I display red if the dB values are very low and display green if the dB values are big enough (by accumulating and calculating the average of rmsdB values during speech)

My issue currently is the slowness of getting the rmsdB values from SpeechRecognizer, also sometimes it stops delivering the rmsdB values for a couple seconds then it works again.
Moreover I found it is a bit tricky to use the rmsdB values to determine if user speaks close enough to the microphone  or not.
I also tried using MediaRecorder and used the amplitude values. It is better in term of precision and speed but unfortunately it can’t be combined with Google SpeechRecognizer so I dropped it since I need to keep the SpeechRecognizer.

Does anybody have experience with calculating distance to microphone in Android using speech sound level ?
Any idea what the best way is to determine if the user speak close enough to microphone or not,
would be appreciated.
Thanks.